# WPF: Binding a Recursive Dictionary to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, treeview

I want to use XAML to display a TreeView of `Dictionary<string, object>`. Every Dictionary's Value is either a `string`, a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, object[]>`. I'm unable to find XAML that displays all three cases. The following XAML will show a nice TreeView but the terminal nodes (string), are blank lines. What's the correct XAML or do I have to use a converter?

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Ultimately I decided that the Dictionary was not well structured for TreeView. I wrote code to traverse the Dictionary and produce well structured TreeViewItem nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more than one template with specialization for the `string`s:

```
<TreeView xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple hierarchical data templates, then use an `ItemTemplateSelector` to select between them based on the type of the object being displayed.